# Newbie on express.js session: who initializes the session

Tags: session, express

saw this example

```
var sess;

app.get('/',function(req,res){
sess=req.session;
//Session set when user Request our app via URL
if(sess.email)
{
/*
* This line check Session existence.
* If it existed will do some action.
*/
res.redirect('/admin');
}
else{
res.render('index.html');
}
});

app.post('/login',function(req,res){
sess=req.session;
//In this we are assigning email to sess.email variable.
//email comes from HTML page.
sess.email=req.body.email;
res.end('done');
});
```

my tiny understanding is: when user login， server generates session id to him/her, assuming this is the login for the 1st time.
But in the above login code,
1. sess = req.session，sounds like client creates a session object at first ?
   or client is creating a session storage space ?
2. who sets session.id or sessionID ?
3. any better example ?

The original sample is here
https://codeforgeek.com/2014/09/manage-session-using-node-js-express-4/

Comment: `app.use(session({secret: 'ssshhhhh'}));` is the `express-session` middleware which takes care of initiating the session id.

Comment: still confused by "sess=req.session;" in the login, can you please add more details ? thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I am also learning node just like you. If you continue your journey, you will encounter so many similar curiousness because way node works behind the modules.

I also had so many question marks but I couldn't afford to search for right answer everytime. what I suggest is get node-inspector, a node debugger tool, and actually follow through.

That way you will actually understand what each module is doing.

instruction: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=03qGA-GJXjI

Big tip that this instruction doesnt tell is fact that node breakpoint is bit weird.

I would definitely use "debugger;" code which puts breakpoint, rather than breakpointer that provided by tool.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i'm on a tough schedule, need to understand concert 1st before coding, e.g. i'm pretty confused on where session.id got used in client and server side, etc.

Comment: i mean concept, not concert